# What would be the correct check syntax for these strings?

Tags: php, mysql, directory

I am writting a script that checks a folder K:/Comics and inserts each name + number into a database, table name = comics. Now what i would like to do would be to check to see if this comic already exists before we run the insert queries.

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comics` (
  `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `issue` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bio` longtext NOT NULL,
  `pages` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `size` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

Code:

```
<?php
    $main_folder = 'K:/Comics/'; // should be K:\Comics\ but I changed it because of the highlighting issue
    $folders = glob($main_folder.'* [0-9]*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

    $comics_series = array();
    foreach($folders as $folder){
        $comics_series[] = preg_split('/(.+)\s(\d+)/', str_replace($main_folder, '', $folder), -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    }

    $values = array();
    foreach($comics_series as $pair){
        $values[] = "('".mysql_real_escape_string($pair[0])."', '".((int) $pair[1])."')";
    }

    $query = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO comics (name, issue) VALUES '.implode(',', $values);
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    echo ($result) ? 'Inserted successfully' : 'Failed to insert the values';
?>
```

What I thought would work but doesn't (still adds comics to the db that are already there):

```
$query = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO comics (name, issue) VALUES '.implode(',', $values);
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo ($result) ? 'Inserted successfully' : 'Failed to insert the values';
```

What did I forget?!? The documentation said just to add `IGNORE` in there and it would work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$main_folder = 'K:/Comics/';
$folders = glob($main_folder.'* [0-9]*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

$comics_series = array();
foreach($folders as $folder){
    $comics_series[] = preg_split('/(.+)\s(\d+)/', str_replace($main_folder, '', $folder), -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}

$values = array();
foreach($comics_series as $pair){
    // clean the values to protect against SQL injection
    $pair = array(
        mysql_real_escape_string($pair[0]),
        mysql_real_escape_string($pair[1])
    );
    // add it to the values array, for insert
    $values[] = "('".$pair[0]."', '".$pair[1]."')";
}

$query = 'INSERT INTO comics (name, issue) VALUES '.implode(',', $values).' '.
         'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `issue` = VALUES(`issue`)';
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo ($result) ? 'Inserted successfully' : 'Failed to insert the values';
?>
```

Comment: `$query = 'INSERT INTO comics (name, issue) VALUES '.implode(',', $values).' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE comicissue=comicissue';` I made name, issue a unique key named comicissue. but it still doesn't work, get a failed to insert the values. I will try this new code now thank you!

Comment: `Failed to insert the values. Duplicate entry '2000AD-1722' for key 'comicissue' `. It doesnt skip over records already there...

Comment: Updated my answer, check that.

Comment: Beautiful, except some comics aren't getting formatted right (only about 20), I can just go back and edit those myself. Thank you so much man you rock!!!

Comment: for some reason it leaves out 0 in the issue, i.e. `Spider-Man 01` gets inserted as `Spider-Man 1`.

Comment: Fixed the issue for the `01`'s. What would you like to do if a title doesn't have an issue number?

Comment: if there is no issue number at the end of the folder name then input the folder name as the name & 0 into the issue field.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id` = `id`' at line 1

Comment: I updated my answer. See if that works, otherwise I am done with this. I did the best I could. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query()` returns a result resource, not an integer or set of values or anything else.  Try changing

```
if ($check_query == '0'){
```

to

```
if (mysql_num_rows($check_query) == 0){
```

However, I would probably just use:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO ...
```

Since it probably doesn't matter.  Check out the [MySQL Insert Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) for more info.

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...` does not work, it still adds all the existing comics to the database again.

Comment: Then you need to put unique keys onto the fields which need to be unique, probably like so: `ALTER TABLE comics ADD UNIQUE KEY name_issue (name, issue)`

Answer (score 1):

`doesn't work` is not too informative.

- Use [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows) instead of `== '0'`, it's really meaningless
- There are no surrounding quotes around the `$values`.
- Wrap the values with parentheses

Comment: sorry it does nothing just leaves me with a blank page

Comment: +1 for wrapping the values in parens, I completely missed this.  Check out the INSERT syntax I linked in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would place a [combined unique index](http://www.opensourcevarsity.com/mysqldba/creatingmysqlcompositeuniqueindex) on the `name` and `issue` columns of the table to enforce the combination of these values to be distinct within the table.

You could then do the following and not worry about double records:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO comics (name, issue) VALUES '.implode(',', $values).'
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id'; //makes sure you don't get an error
```

You could also use the `INSERT IGNORE` statement *(as stated by @Dereleased)* to avoid inserts of duplicates *(in the before specified [unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html))*.

Also see the documentation for the [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) statement, it might be helpfull in situations where you want to update the record if it was found as a duplicate while inserting.

Comment: `$query = 'INSERT INTO comics (name, issue) VALUES '.implode(',', $values).' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE comicissue=comicissue';` I made name, issue a unique key named comicissue. but it still doesn't work, get a failed to insert the values.

Comment: I guess you get an error about `comicissue` not existing as a column *(or something of that nature)*? Try using the statement with `id=id` instead of `comicissue=comicissue`. This should work if the table structure in you original question is correct.

Comment: If you don't want to worry about the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement you could do the following: `$query = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO comics (name, issue) VALUES '.implode(',', $values);`

Comment: `$query = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO comics (name, issue) VALUES '.implode(',', $values);` That still doesn't skip over the ones already there. I tried that one.

Comment: it errors out on folders names `Secret Avengers 012.1` & `S.H.I.E.L.D. - Infinity`

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query returns a statement handle if the query succeeds, and boolean FALSE if the query fails. You'd need to do:

```
$check_query_result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($check_query_result) == 0) {
   ... comic doesn't exist ...
}
```

Note that a query returning no rows is NOT a failure condition. It's simply a result that happened to have no rows